# Laravel 6 , request()->validate no funciona

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

Estoy haciendo un formulario que permite subir imágenes a un servidor usando laravel.

Al comienzo, el formulario sirve, tengo la función:

```php
dd(request()->all());
```

Recibiendo así el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que tengo en el Controller es:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function create(){
    return view ('posts/create');
    }

    public function store(){

        dd(request()->all());

    $data = request()->validate([
    'caption' => 'required',
    'image' => ['required', 'image'],
    ]);

    auth()->User()->posts()->create($data);


    }
}
```

Obviamente saco la función "dd"

Hago correr la función y la página se reinicia, con la imagen no subiendose a la base de datos.

Pongo la función de dd **después** de $data = request.... para ver si hay algo, pero no hay nada, la página simplemente se reinicia

¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

¿Es esto algo que viene con Laravel 6? estoy siguiendo un tutorial que usa laravel 5

Comment: Me da los mismos resultados lamentablemente

Comment: Creo que el `request` debería ser tomado del párametro del `store($request)`

Comment: store(request $request) ?

Answer (score 2):

Es un poco particular no inyectar el objeto Request en un método para guardar. Hay algunas diferencias menores entre usar el helper y traer directamente el objeto:

```
public function store(Request $request) 
{

    // ...

    $data = $request->validate([ ...
```

Si bien nunca he intentado trabajar con el helper de esa manera, la convención sugiere inyectar el Request cuando se va a trabajar con store.

Comment: Me dio error fatal: Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\{closure}() must be of 
 the type array, object given

Comment: Revisa en qué línea está ese error, y corrígela.

Comment: La acabo de corregir, vuelvo al 1er problema, con la página reiniciandose

Comment: ¿Qué esperas que ocurra? no veo ningún return o similar en tu código.

Comment: al usar php artisan tinker, se muestra que se sube la imagen (en caso de que no haya un usuario logueado, envía mensaje de error)

No ocurre ninguno de los dos ,   También tengo la función dd, por ende debería aparecer algo parecido a lo de la imagen