# La función $request->validate([]) no sólo es inaccesible, sino que "reinicia" la pagina web, cancelando otras funciones

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

Estoy haciendo una función en laravel 6 que permite el subir imágenes asignadas a un perfil, para aquello tengo un formulario que se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y para subir las imágenes uso el siguiente código:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function create(){
    return view ('posts/create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request){

    $validatedData = $request->validate([
    'caption' => 'required',
    'image' => ['required', 'image'],
    ]);
    dd(request()->all());
    auth()->User()->posts()->create($data);

    }
}
```

Código que hice siguiendo la documentación propia de laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation junto con un tutorial de youtube sobre como usar laravel (el tutorial usa laravel 5)

El problema viene que al ejecutarlo (dígase, subir una imagen), la página se reinicia completamente (dejando lo que sea que escribí como descripción) y los datos no se suben a la base de datos. De hecho, se supone que tiene que salir un error de que no hay un usuario con una sesión activa, no aparece.

Decidí usar el comando:

```php
dd(request()->all());
```

Para ver si se reciben los datos, al comienzo lo puse antes que:

```php
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'caption' => 'required',
    'image' => ['required', 'image'],
]);
```

Y sí se muestran datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después moví esa linea de código después de $request->validate, y la página se reinicia, no alcanza ni a llegar a la función "dd".

¿Alguien sabe porque pasa esto? ¿Falta algo que instalar o hay un error de sintaxis que no puedo ver?

Comment: ¿El problema es que debería detectar que no hay una sesión activa de usuario o que aparentemente no funciona la validación? Son dos cosas muy distintas.

Comment: la validación no funciona, porque ya sea con o sin un usuario activo (probé de ambas formas) el resultado es el mismo.

De todas formas, se debería ver algo parecido a mi segunda imagen

Comment: Creo que el problema es que no entiendes cómo funciona la validación.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Laravel 6 , request()->validate no funciona](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/326723/laravel-6-request-validate-no-funciona)

Answer (score 4):

lo que ocurre es que `$validate` tiene `return back()` incorporado en caso de fallar la `validacion` , agrega codigo para capturar el error, en tu caso se ve que esperas `caption -> required` pero en el `dd()` no pasas ningun parametro con ese `nombre` , en todo caso seria

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'description' => ['required'],
    'image' => ['required', 'image'],
]);
```

**Caption [descripcion]**

```
@error('description')
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span>
@enderror
```

**Imagen**

```
@error('image')
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span>
@enderror
```

Answer (score 2):

Uhhmmm....me van a querer matar por esto, no, me querrán desterrar de este plano existencial por lo que voy a decir...

Fue un error gramatical, en vez de caption tenia escrito cation en el formulario html y en la create_table.

...perdón

Comment: ¡Al calabozo de StackOverflow! :D

Comment: Entonces recomiendo elimines tu pregunta pues es solo un error gramatical y por favor entonces no maarques la otra respuesta como aceptada